# Django permissions are not getting cached

Tags: django, postgresql, caching, permissions

I am using django 1.11, postgres with `@permission_required` decorator in my django views. The problem is that for any view, I get 2 extra SQL queries -

1) `SELECT ••• FROM "auth_permission" INNER JOIN "account_myuser_user_permissions" ON ...`

2) `SELECT ••• FROM "auth_permission" INNER JOIN "auth_group_permissions" ON ...`

The Django docs state that -
`The ModelBackend caches permissions on the user object after the first time they need to be fetched for a permissions check.`

I am unable to understand why the permissions are not getting cached the first time, or am I missing something?

Comment: Those are two different queries - one for permissions on the user, and one for permissions on the group(s) that the user belongs to.

Comment: @solarissmoke Yes, so shouldn't the user permissions be cached atleast?

Comment: They are cached for the lifetime of the object, not for the lifetime of your wsgi process. A new request will fetch the object again from the database, and for any further uses of that object during that request, the permissions will be cached. They will not be cached between requests.

Comment: @solarissmoke I had a hunch that was the case. Thanks for clarifying!